# Vue webpack encore sass source map not working correctly

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, source-maps, webpack-encore

I am working on a Vue project integrated with webpack (no Vue CLI).
Everything works fine functionality-wise.
But when I track/debug a style from any page the chrome devtools show me `App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&` instead of showing the actual scss file (eg. `user-profile.scss) code.

for example,

[image]

I want to see the `scss` file for that particular code (eg. `user-profile.scss` instead of `App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss`).

However, I can see the bootstrap `scss` files are being displayed correctly,

[image]

It's just that all `scss` files of my project being shown as a single file in the chrome inspector.
I am able to debug the components, module files etc but just the scss/css part of the sourcemap not seems to be working.

Here is my webpack config,

```
Encore
  .setOutputPath('public/build/')
  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
  .enableBuildNotifications()
  .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
  .configureBabel(() => {
  }, {
    useBuiltIns: 'usage',
    corejs: 3
  })
  .enableVueLoader()
  .enableSassLoader()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
  .disableSingleRuntimeChunk()
  .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.js')
  .configureFilenames(setFilenames)
;
```

In the `App.vue` I'm importing a single file (`assets/sass/index`) which imports different styles for different pages in that file. ex `App.vue`

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import './assets/sass/index';
</style>
```

am I missing something?
Thanks

Note: I have enabled sourcemap in chrome dev tools settings

Comment: Well you need sass sourcemaps. It should be easy with webpack. But you are using Encore. So you should probably google for some solutions here

Comment: @Arseniy-II Thanks for the suggestion. But why does the other third party's source maps load (eg. as I mentioned in the question, the Bootstrap's scss source maps are showing the scss code correctly)

Comment: Most likely because you import bootstrap css file. But *your* custom css is compiled by webpack. So you need to provide source maps to *your* css files. I don't know how to do that with encore.